# Возможно ли подогнать сайт под все браузеры?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Господа, ответьте на вопрос, возможно ли подогнать верстку сайта под все браузеры и все возможные разрешения экранов, чтобы везде сайт смотрелся идеально? Если нет, то какие разрешения считаются самыми популярными и часто используются?

Comment: В такой постановке вопрос не имеет смысла. Простейшая разметка вида 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body />     
   </html>

всегда и везде будет выглядеть идеально.

Answer (score 7):

```
Да, возможно. Вот код страницы такого сайта:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Везде работающий сайт</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p>Везде работающий сайт</p>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Главное, больше ничего не трогать, не добавлять и не изменять в этом коде.

Comment: Шикарный сайт а если серьезно ??

Comment: @alexsis20102 - серьезнее некуда

Comment: В большинстве случаев - можно

Comment: *@istem можно и проще*

**Пустой файл будет тоже везде смотреться одинокого**

Comment: @alexsis20102, а если серьёзно, то это проблема дизайна/интерфейса.  Спроектировать проект, используя исключительно нативные, кроссбраузерные и, главное, стандартные элементы. Так как разработчики браузеров, отлаживают и доводят до ума - именно их, остальные расширения - как получится.